# How to import fullcalendar v.3.0.1 with systemjs?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have app.ts

```
import moment from 'moment/moment';
import $ from "jquery";
import 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar';

$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

But having the error that $(...).fullCalendar is not a function.
Hope some one can guide me to solve this.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty, not via angular/node, but client-side.

Ended up getting it to work via

```
System.config({
    map: {
        fullcalendar: "/js/app/fullcalendar-3.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"
    },
    meta: {
        fullcalendar: {
            deps: [
                // not sure why, but moment.js needs placed under "globals"
            ],
            format: "global",
            globals: {
                moment: "/js/app/fullcalendar-3.3.1/lib/moment.min.js"
            }
        }
    }
});


System.import("fullcalendar").then(function(){
    // tada fullcalendar is loaded
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({});
});
```