# Angular hybrid app, typeerror calendar.fullcalendar is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular, calendar, fullcalendar, systemjs

I am working on an application that uses AngularJS and Angular (2+). In the new version, I am using system.js to import the Angular app. Without the system.js import the calendar works fine, but with system.js there is a problem to initialize.

I have tried the trick below with `calendar = $(elm);` with no luck.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/267

Even trying `var calendar = $('#calendar’)`.

The problem does not seem to be in recognizing that there exists a calendar element. From what I can infer logging the framework’s source code, when working correctly, the calendar element has these classes when initializing.

```
div#calendar.calendar.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-isolate-scope.fc.fc-cursor.fc-ltr.fc-unthemed
```

Currently the initialize is trying to use this as the calendar element which throws the `angular.min.js:117 TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function` error, it still finds the correct element but does not append the classes to it.

```
div#calendar.calendar.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-isolate-scope
```

script.ejs

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<—-! All the AngularJS -—>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<!-- Moment -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-1hjUhpc44NwiNg8OwMu2QzJXhD8kcj+sJA3aCQZoUjg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- ui calendar -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-calendar/1.0.0/calendar.min.js" integrity="sha256-DBa6dvjY39GU4NQ2Ia2CIPVFszxgZ4N3JccyPvJNPLI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

AngularJS only app, index.ejs :

```
<body>
  <div id="shell" data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="shellController">

    …

  </div>


  <%- include partials/scripts %>

</body>
```

Hybrid app index.ejs :

```
<body class="full-width">
  <div id="shell" data-ng-controller="shellController">

  …

  </div>


  <%- include partials/scripts %>

  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error('ERR from import: ’,err); });
  </script>


</body>
```

I am using v 2.7.1 of fullcalendar, and v 1.0.0 of angular-ui-calendar. Any help to what might be the cause of this problem would be extremely appreciated, I’ve been looking at this for days!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with this post.

[How to import fullcalendar v.3.0.1 with systemjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184954/how-to-import-fullcalendar-v-3-0-1-with-systemjs)

Turns out the problem lay in the moment.js file not being within the `meta` property within the system.js config.